# Display the popup view when the filtering is under process

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my group's project, we had a one grid and export button. We came across an issue which is that when exopt the data in excel format fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SZBrt/11/ need to display the pop up message stating that 'The data is getting filtered' to be displayed so that the we can know the filtering is under process. I appreciate your help in advance.

And My Code:

```
      var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type           : "odata",
            transport      : {
                read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
            },
            schema         : {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        OrderID  : { type: "number" },
                        Freight  : { type: "number" },
                        ShipName : { type: "string" },
                        OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                        ShipCity : { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize       : 10
        },
        filterable: true,
        sortable  : true,
        pageable  : true,
        columns   : [
            {
                field     : "OrderID",
                filterable: false
            },
            "Freight",
            {
                field : "OrderDate",
                title : "Order Date",
                width : 100,
                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
            },
            {
                field: "ShipName",
                title: "Ship Name",
                width: 200
            },
            {
                field: "ShipCity",
                title: "Ship City"
            }
        ]
    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to the `DataSource` definition an event handler for `requestStart` and `requestEnd`.

```
dataSource: {
    requestStart : function() {
        // Add code for displaying your own "loading" message
    },
    requestEnd:    function() {
        // Add code for hiding your own "loading" message
    },
    type           : "odata",
            transport      : {
        read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
    },
    schema         : {
        model: {
            fields: {
                OrderID  : { type: "number" },
                Freight  : { type: "number" },
                ShipName : { type: "string" },
                OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                ShipCity : { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize       : 10
},
```

You did not specify how that *Loading* message looks like, it might be as simple as adding / removing visibility:

```
requestStart: function () {
    $("#loading-msg").css("visibility", "visible");
},
requestEnd: function () {
    $("#loading-msg").css("visibility", "hidden");
},
```

or open / close a window:

```
requestStart: function () {
    $("#loading-msg").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
},
requestEnd: function () {
    $("#loading-msg").data("kendoWindow").close();
},
```

Comment: Of course, you did not create the window so cannot open / close it. See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/SZBrt/26/)

Comment: ya thank you so much for your quick reply but pop up is not closing automatically after loading data and after filter clicking "clear button" popup is raising that's good by pop-up is not closing automatically  http://jsfiddle.net/MG89G/386/

Comment: Yep! you moved to the past: you changed the version of KendoUI and in that version `requestEnd` did not exist. Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/MG89G/387/)

Comment: Is it acceptable for you moving to a newer release of KendoUI or you need to use that old one?